# jQuery Range Slider is not loading in Modal Box

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, slider, rangeslider

I am trying to load [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/) in a modal box. 
After load all [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/) scripts.
Scripts loaded Successfully but Modal box is not showing with [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/)

**What I am trying to do.**

There is listing of `id`. 
Click on each `id` ajax called and fetched the slider data from backend(MySql).

then a model box will appear with slider. Slider have the information whitch are fetched from backend(MySql) according to `id`.

There is lot of `id` in list. so it is not possible to set a static slider.

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Njhvv/2/

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#sliderAjaxButton").on('click', function () {
         $.when(
         $.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSlider.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderMouseTouch.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderDraggable.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderBar.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderHandle.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRangeSliderLabel.js"),
         $.getScript("http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/jQRuler.js")

         ).done(function () {
             alert("Loaded all scripts");

         $("#sliderAjax").modal({
             "show": function(){
                 setTimeout(function(){
                      $("#sliderAjaxShow").rangeSlider("resize");
                 }, 500);
             }
         });

         });
     });
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="" id='sliderAjaxButton'>Show Slider Ajax</button>
   <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="sliderAjax" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id='sliderAjaxShow'>...</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Updated :**

I am trying to load a Range Slider in Bootstrap Model Box.

**Problem:** 
First time it is not loading Properly. But after second time It is loading proper.

what i need : I need to load this in first attempt.

What I am doing: It is Showing on every JS tree leaf click. after click on Leaf a JSON will call to give data input to slider. With JSON data slider sets its postilion.

My linked Question :[jQuery Range Slider is not loading in Modal Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411886/jquery-range-slider-is-not-loading-in-modal-box)

i have also tried with **$.when()** but still there is same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `$("#sliderAjaxShow").rangeSlider("resize")` once the modal is shown, because jQRangeSlider calculates its position based on its size (which is 0 when the parent is hidden).

1. Add **CSS rules** to your fiddle, or you won't see anything.
2. Use the **minified file**, otherwise you'll have to include each development file in the *right order*.
3. Call **resize** when the modal is displayed (after the animation). As jQuery UI does not provide an event triggered once the animation is done, you'll have to bind the event **show**
   and call resize with timeout.

Something like

```
$("#sliderAjax").modal({
             "show": function(){
                 setTimeout(function(){
                      $("#sliderAjaxShow").rangeSlider("resize");
                 }, 500);
             }
         });
```

Take a look at the documentation here, you'll see a live example of an hidden slider displayed on demand: https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/methods.html#resizeMethod

Comment: I'm testing with Firefox, and I still have critical errors, meaning that jQuery and jQueryUI are not correctly loaded when the code is called. 
  TypeError: $.ui is undefined jQRangeSliderMouseTouch.js:13
  TypeError: $.ui is undefined jQRangeSliderDraggable.js:12
  TypeError: $.widget is not a function jQRuler.js:115
  TypeError: s is not a constructor jquery-ui.min.js:5
  TypeError: $(...)[this._handleType(...)] is not a function

Comment: Sir i have updated the Fiddle but problem is same. 
As i have come to know you are the developer of this Plugin.:)

Comment: I edited the answer. Be sure to follow the steps, and check you don't have any JS error in the log.

Comment: Updated the fiddle with css and jquery but still have problem..Modal box working but slider not showing.

Comment: There is listing of id. Click on each id ajax will call and will fetch the slider data from backend(MySql).

then a model box will appear with slider . slider have the information with are fetched from backend(MySql) accoring to id.

There is lot of id in list. so it is not possible to set a static slider.

Comment: As written in step 2: use THE MINIFIED FILE instead of including all development files, otherwiser YOU MUST include them in the RIGHT ORDER (which you are not doing). Download the package from here : https://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/ and include the package source.

Comment: sir i am not getting this.What you are saying ?. could you please edit my fiddle as you are saying..?

Comment: There is still a problem with CSS styles, but the thing is working: http://jsfiddle.net/M43Ga/